# iOS - limiting the arrayIndex between 0 and 98

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, indexing, unsigned-integer

in my project i have an array of images. The images are displayed on an imageView, i can move between the images with swipes. But when i get to zero and swipe left (aka previous photo, which decreases the arrayIndex by one) i get an error (SIGABRT).
here's my code that's responsible for moving between images:

```
-(IBAction)nextPhoto:(id)sender{
arrayIndex++;
NSLog(@"rigth! at index %lu", arrayIndex);
if (arrayIndex <= 98){
displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]];
} else {
    displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
}

}
-(IBAction)previousPhoto:(id)sender{
 arrayIndex--;
 NSLog(@"Left! at index %lu", arrayIndex);
 if (arrayIndex >= 0){
 displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray  objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]];
} else {
   displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:98]];
}

}
```

Comment: Is `arrayIndex` an `NSUInteger`?

Comment: yes arrayIndex is an NSUInteger by default.

Comment: The U in NSUInteger stands for unsigned, which means the variable can't be less than 0. If you decrement an unsigned int with the value 0 it will wrap to `2^64 - 1`, which is very big but still positive. If you run the analyzer it should warn you that the else branch will never be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show us the declaration of `arrayIndex`, but I guess it's `unsigned long`, since you print it with `%lu`.

Consider what happens when `arrayIndex == 0`:

```
// arrayIndex == 0
arrayIndex--;
// Now arrayIndex == ULONG_MAX.
// The following condition is always true for unsigned longs.
if (arrayIndex >= 0){
    // This branch is always taken.
    // The following objectAtIndex: fails for ULONG_MAX.
    displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray  objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]];
```

You need to check for `arrayIndex == 0` **before** you decrement it, like this:

```
-(IBAction)nextPhoto:(id)sender {
    ++arrayIndex;
    if (arrayIndex >= imageArray.count) {
        arrayIndex = 0;
    }
    displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageArray[arrayIndex]];
}

-(IBAction)previousPhoto:(id)sender {
    if (arrayIndex == 0) {
        arrayIndex = imageArray.count - 1;
    } else {
        --arrayIndex;
    }
    displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageArray[arrayIndex]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `arrayIndex` is an unsigned integer, when `arrayIndex` is 0 and you say:

```
arrayIndex--;
```

This causes it to wrap around to a very large number, which is >= 0. You should check to see if arrayIndex > 0 before decrementing it. For example, if you want your images to wrap:

```
-(IBAction)previousPhoto:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Left! at index %lu", arrayIndex);
    if (arrayIndex == 0) {
        arrayIndex = 98;
    } else {
        arrayIndex--;
    }
    displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray  objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]];
}
```

Comment: can you explain where would i put the if statement?

Comment: @iOSDvlpr I've added an example. You might also consider using imageArray.count instead of hard-coding numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are never modifying `arrayIndex` wrapping cases. This should do it:

```
-(IBAction)nextPhoto:(id)sender{
arrayIndex++;
NSLog(@"rigth! at index %lu", arrayIndex);
if (arrayIndex <= 98){
displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]];
} else {
    arrayIndex = 0;
    displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]];
}

}
-(IBAction)previousPhoto:(id)sender{
 arrayIndex--;
 NSLog(@"Left! at index %lu", arrayIndex);
 if (arrayIndex >= 0){
 displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray  objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]];
} else {
   arrayIndex = 98;
   displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]];
}

}
```

Comment: i still get this error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (-1 (or possibly larger)) beyond bounds (99)'

Comment: is arrayIndex an unsigned integer? if so, you need to make it a signed integer instead in order for this work, or check to see if it should be wrapped before adding/subtracting from it. Making it an `NSInteger` should be enough though.

Comment: ArrayIndex can only be an unsigned integer.

Comment: No, your `arrayIndex` variable can be whatever you want it to be. AN array index can only be an unsigned integer but your variable does not need to conform to that as long as you make sure it is within the expected range yourself (which is what the code above does).

Comment: So you're suggesting that i change arrayIndex to NSInteger?

Comment: Yes, that would work. But you already marked one of the other answers as correct (that answer is indeed also correct, there is more than one way to do this). Did it not work?

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore, but it skips 99 and 0

Comment: You said your array goes up to index 98, not 99.

Comment: Yes, it goes from 1 to 98